# Analogue to emirp for Carmichael numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, carmichael-numbers

An emirp is a prime number with the property that if we write down the digits in base $10$ in reverse , we again get a prime number. Trivial emirp's are the palindrome primes (if we write down the digits in reverse , we get the same prime number).

> What about Carmichael numbers with the property that writing down them in reverse (of course again in base $10$) leads to another Carmichael number ?

The Carmichael number $101101$ is a trivial case (palindrome). It is so far the only Carmichael number I found with this property. I have not checked the database upto $10^{21}$ yet.

$15709$ is the smallest example , if we only demand the number to be composite and to pass the weak fermat test with base $2$ , but neither of the numbers are Carmichael numbers.

I am curious whether there is a nontrivial case. or at least further palindromes.

Comment: No further example upto $10^{10}$

Comment: `127665878878566721` is an example of another palindrome Carmichael number (checked the database up to $10^{18}$ to find it). I did not find a non-trivial case.

Comment: @jorisperrenet That makes a further example unlikely. Thanks.

Comment: Checking a larger database that goes up to $2^{64}$ these are still the only examples.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4729220/82961)