# Are there more Teluop-numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, palindrome, pseudoprimes, carmichael-numbers

This is not a yet known terminology , but I suggest it for Poulet-numbers with the property that they give another Poulet-number , if the decimal expansion is written down in reverse order analogue to the emirp's (primes that given another prime if their decimal expansion is written down in reverse).

A poulet-number is a composite number $N$ satisfying the congruence $2^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$ , so it passes the weak $2$-fermat-test.

A "Teluop-number" is called "trivial" if it is a palindrome (the deicmal expansion written in reverse order gives the same number)

There are $5$ examples below $10^5$ :

```
gp > forstep(n=3,10^8,2,if(Mod(2,n)^(n-1)==1,if(ispseudoprime(n)==0,m=fromdigits(Vecrev(digits(n)));if(Mod(2,m)^(m-1)==1,if(ispseudoprime(m)==0,print(n))))))
15709
90751
101101
129921
1837381
gp >
```

$$127665878878566721$$ is a palindrome Carmichael-number.

In the database of the Carmichael-numbers upto $2^{64}$ , there is no other such entry , only $101101$ and the large number given above. There is no "nontrivial" example. In total , we have four trivial "Teluop-numbers" and one nontrivial pair (the reverse of a Teluop-number is of course a Teluop-number).

I have no access to the database of the Poulet-numbers upto $2^{64}$.

> Are there more examples in the database ? Is the number of Teluop-numbers infinite ? I think not because Poulet-numbers get very rare if the magnitude gets over , say , $10^{20}$.

In particular interesting would be a nontrivial Carmichael-number with the above property.

Comment: Current search limit : $4\cdot 10^9$

Comment: One further trivial Teluop-number below $2^{64}$: $ 1037998220228997301$

Comment: Wow ! Again a huge example !

Comment: I did the same search as @MartinHopf did and can confirm that the ones mentioned are the only Teluop-numbers below $2^{64}$.

Comment: Heuristically we expect the number of Teluop-numbers to be finite, see [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PouletNumber.html) for the upper bound of Poulet-numbers and multiply by the chance of a number being a palindrome. Thus, unless Poulet-numbers are somehow drawn to palindromicness the number of Teluop-numbers are finite.

Comment: Also, from the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001567) on Poulet-numbers, a number $n=q(2q-1)$ is Poulet if both $q$ and $2q-1$ are primes and $q$ is of the form $12k+1$. I searched the numbers of this form and found no (trivial) Teluop-number $\leq 10^{31}$. $q=13347462829$ came close, it results in a palindrome and it is prime but $2q-1$ is not.

Comment: @jorisperrenet I am always baffled how fast you cover such astronomical search limits. Since you seem to have a fantastic hardware , there is another project you can join in (if you want) - the ec-primes. In the room "Martin Hopf's prime numbers" you can get the necessary informations.

Comment: A $21$-digit palindrome ! Amazing !